# Error with pyspark "Java gateway process exited before sending its port number"

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am facing two errors in Spark 3.1.2 and Hadoop 2.7:

First one when import 'pyspark' in python and create a session.

> ERROR: 'Java gateway process exited before sending its port number'

Second one occured when I tried running "pyspark" in powershell to see if it is working

> ERROR: '& was unexpected at this time.'

I followed the exact installation instructions from https://spark.apache.org. Also, I tried multiple solutions provided here in Stack Overflow with no luck.

I feel the issue with 'winutils.exe'

I downloaded them from the repository on GitHub for the following Hadoop versions: [2.7.1, 2.7.7]

Tried them and none worked.

My environment variables -as far as I checked- are all right:

```
SPARK_HOME
HADOOP_HOME
JAVA_HOME
```

In path:

```
%SPARK_HOME%\bin
%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
```

Is there something I missed or the new Spark just not working for me?

Please: if you would like to see any log files, kindly give me the command to execute it and give you back the logs.

- Windows 10
- Python: 3.7.10
- Anaconda: 4.10.3
- Java: 1.8.0_251
- Spark: 3.1.2
- Hadoop: 2.7

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out the error after trying multiple solutions for the problem.
So, I reseted my windows and now everything is working, which got my to think.
Before the reset, I installed Windows terminal from Windows store and made some them adjustment. I do not know how it is related to my spark issue, but it seems it.